# How to match several parts of the string

Tags: php, regex

Let's say I have a string such as

```
$path = '/files/2012/12/49/3/192/1922243/3f121ad91c06b15e_IMG_1680__59967.1347548784.1280.1280.xxlarge/i/Blah-Something-Random.jpg';
```

I want to extract 1st group which is everything after /files/ to /i/ and then also second group which is the ending extensionextension .jpg (sometimes it might be .png etc)

so basically after reg ex replaces runs I want it to look like this

> $path =
>   '2012/12/49/3/192/1922243/3f121ad91c06b15e_IMG_1680__59967.1347548784.1280.1280.xxlarge.jpg';

I got to part to extract the first group between /files/ to /i/ but can't figure out how to extract the last .jpg part aka second group.

this is what I have so far

```
$file_path = preg_replace('/\/files\/(.*?)\/i\/.*/', '${1}', $path);
```

Comment: you could explode on / and join back the bits you want

Comment: Did you figure out the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here you go

```
/\/files\/(.*?)\/i\/.*(\.\w+)$/
```